# Network connection icon showing X mark

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have connected the LAN cable and the LEDs at LAN port are blinking with green and orange, but I am unable to connect to the internet. There is an 'X' mark on the network connection icon and it is showing not connected. If I connect the same cable to other system I am able to get the internet.

I am using Windows 7 professional 32 bit OS. I have even changed the hard disk to other system assuming that the problem might be with the LAN port but I have faced the same issue again.

Comment: Please add details like your OS. When you say you "changed the hard disk to another system...but I have faced the same issue", are you saying that in after moving your HDD to a new computer, the new computer also shows the X?

Comment: Can you please check whether the LAN connection is disabled in your  machine

Comment: Yes I am using Windows 7 proffessional, when I change the HDD to new system I faced the same X mark

Answer (score 0):

A complete reinstall seems a bit premature at this point. Why not first try the following:

1. Clear all preferred wireless networks from your network configuration. Right click to manage, click wireless on the left, delete everything.
2. Ensure the network manager service is running.

A reboot may be required, but it was not in my case.